# UISwitch in notifications center

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiswitch

I'm making an app and want to save the value of UISwitch either on or off to be saved in notifications center but I don't understand how to save the value of it

any solution will be appericated

Comment: values can not be stored in notification center
notification use for sending and receiving values

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store your data ( on or off status ) you can use userdefaults.

You can set data by doing this:

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set(value: yourData forKey: "yourKey")
```

To retrieve the data

```
 let myData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "yourKey")
```